# How do you auto start Node JS server with PM2?

Tags: pm2, autostart

How do I auto start a javascript server with pm2? I normally run this command to start the javascript server:

```
oneanime config.json
```

so what would the command be to run in pm2?
I'm temporary using a bash script to run it in pm2 but I prefer run the command directly in pm2 instead of relying bash script.

Comment: Do you mean Node JS server?

Comment: @Deividgp yes I meant nodejs

Comment: Try `pm2 start oneanime -- --config.json`.

Comment: @Deividgp tried that but it didn't work

Comment: `pm2 start oneanime -- config.json` doesn't work either? I just found https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/13 , you might find it helpful.